# How to join where there is a possibility of no record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Say I have the following schema:

```
create table client (clientid int)
create table mv (clientid int, fundid int, date datetime, value decimal)

insert into client values(1)
insert into mv values(1, 1, '1 may 2010', 35)
insert into mv values (1,1, '1 may 2011', 434)
insert into mv values (1, 2, '1 may 2011', 635)
```

The first table represents the client, and the second table represents their market value and the fund they are invested in.

I need to display their market value per fund at 2 dates, but display 0 for a date if I cant find a record for that date.

Here is my attempt:

```
select 
c.clientid, 
mvstart.fundid startfundid,
mvend.fundid endfundid, 
mvstart.value startvalue,
mvend.value endvalue
from client c
left join mv mvstart 
on c.clientid = mvstart.clientid
and mvstart.date = '1 may 2010'
left join mv mvend 
on c.clientid = mvend.clientid 
and mvend.date = '1 may 2011'
```

Which produces:

```
CLIENTID    STARTFUNDID ENDFUNDID   STARTVALUE  ENDVALUE
1           1           1           35          434
1           1           2           35          635
```

I don't understand why the second row has a startvalue of 35.

I need to have the following output:

```
CLIENTID    FUNDID  STARTVALUE  ENDVALUE
1           1       35          434
1           2       0           635
```

Can anyone help me join correctly or explain why my query produces 35 as the startvalue for the 2nd row?

Heres a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0090f/7)

Comment: cannot test it right now, but at first glance is because you don't put any condition on the mvstart.fundid=mvend.fundid

Comment: thanks, I'll bear that in mind, but for now that would just exclude the 2nd record

Comment: The problem for your query is the line `on c.clientid = mvstart.clientid and mvstart.date = '1 may 2010'`. It only get the value `35` twice, that's why you see `35` twice there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query without joins:

```
SELECT mv.clientid,
       mv.fundid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN date = '1 may 2010' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as startvalue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN date = '1 may 2011' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as endtvalue
FROM mv
GROUP BY clientid,fundid
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0090f/25)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Again bear in mind that I have no access to a db right now :(
This query should do something similar to what you want

```
SELECT 
   X.CLIENTID,
   X.FUNDID,
   Y.STARTVAL,
   Y.ENDVAL
 FROM MV X,
   (SELECT B.CLIENTID, B.FUNDID, 
           COALESCE(A.VALUE,0) STARTVAL, 
           COALESCE(B.VALUE,0) ENDVAL FROM MV A 
    FULL OUTER JOIN MV B
    ON A.CLIENTID=B.CLIENTID AND
       A.FUNDID=B.FUNDID AND
       A.DATE='1 may 2010' AND
       B.DATE='1 may 2011'
 ) Y
  WHERE
     X.CLIENTID=Y.CLIENTID AND 
     X.FUNDID=Y.FUNDID AND 
     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CLIENT C
              WHERE C.CLIENTID=X.CLIENTID)
```

Probably you don't even need to use the client table, but I added it just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select base.clientid, base.fundid, mvs.value, mve.value
from
    (select clientid, fundid, MIN(date) as startdate, MAX(date) as enddate from mv
     group by clientid, fundid ) base,
     mv as mvs,
     mv as mve
where base.clientid = mvs.clientid and base.fundid = mvs.fundid and base.startdate = mvs.date
      and base.clientid = mve.clientid and base.fundid = mve.fundid and base.enddate = mve.date
```

Comment: the startvalue for fund 2 is 635, where it should be 0

Answer (score 0):

I think this will produce proper result:

```
create table #client (clientid int)
create table #mv (clientid int, fundid int, date datetime, value decimal)

insert into #client values(1)
insert into #mv values(1, 1, '1 may 2010', 35)
insert into #mv values (1,1, '1 may 2011', 434)
insert into #mv values (1, 2, '1 may 2011', 635)

select
    c.clientid, 
    mvstart.fundid startfundid,
    mvend.fundid endfundid, 
    mvstart.value startvalue,
    mvend.value endvalue
from #client c
    cross join (select distinct fundid, clientid from #mv mv) fId
    left join #mv mvstart on c.clientid = mvstart.clientid and mvstart.date = '1 may 2010' and mvstart.fundid = fId.fundid
    left join #mv mvend on c.clientid = mvend.clientid and mvend.date = '1 may 2011' and mvend.fundid = fId.fundid
where fId.clientid = c.clientid
```